# How to add an enchantment onto held item in Minecraft with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a button to enchant a piece of armor in my hand with Unbreaking V, if and only if:

- The tool is already enchanted with Unbreaking III
- The player has a minimum of 30 levels

I tried using `/testfor` for a certain enchantment on a certain item ID range, taking away 30 levels, and then enchanting the item in-hand with `/enchant`. But it turns out you cannot use `/enchant` to make higher than default enchantment levels, you can only do that with the `/give` command.

I do not know how I am supposed to use the `/give` command because the item given has to have all the enchantments it had before it was enchanted with Unbreaking V.

Comment: What you wanna do: Testfor Break3 armor -> remove Break3 armor -> `/give` Break5 armor. correct?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 They also seem to want to keep "the same previous enchants" that are on the armor.

Comment: @colorfusion Maybe that means that if there are other enchants, like Protection 2, for example, it won't remove them. Not sure though.

Comment: OP can you clarify it?

Comment: @arceusmaster0493 Yes! Most importantly testfor any armor with a certain enchantment.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 To further clarify, I am using this on a bukkit server and I found a plugin that allows you to add enchantments. All I need is a testfor any armor/tool with unbreaking 3 so to force players to get unbreaking 3 on their armor before they upgrade it to unbreaking 5.

Comment: @Dovahkriid500 I don't know which plug in it is but I only know the way in vanilla. I will try and organise it and post it as an answer.

Comment: Say.. Does the `/entitydata` command work on players?

Comment: @aytimothy Nope

Comment: Well a dumb solution is to add a set of command blocks for every enchant and item combo

Comment: @ModDL I thought of that but at that point I don't even know if it's worth it.

Comment: It's not possible with vanilla mechanics... Not that I can think of | The closest thing to this is the `[Enchant]` signs in the Essentials Bukkit/Spigot/Sponge/whatever-that-is-not-Vanilla-vanilla-servers plugin.

Comment: @Dovahkriid500 I am not sure if I can do the "keep previous enchantments" part. Do all Break3 armors have the same enchantments, or will you let them further enchant an already enchanted item which is impossible in vanilla minecraft? Also, for the testfor part, I think this is the frame of the procedure: `if armor has break3, enchant break5. if not, omit enchant part.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I modify an item while it is inside the player's inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376895/how-can-i-modify-an-item-while-it-is-inside-the-players-inventory)

Comment: Despite the fact that this question has 9 answers, as far as I can tell none of them actually answer the question, and the duplicate does.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the only way would be to add command blocks for every single armor enchant and level combo in the game. (Unless you wanted to host a server on your computer running bukkit and just not allow anyone in. Then you could download [essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/) and use /enchant )

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a two command blocks constantly checking for the tool in one hand and the armour in the other, and have command blocks testing for all enchantment combinations AND testing for the xp level, and somehow linking them all to one output, this system is impossible.

The problem with this task is *format*. A villager generated through a command generator that gives you specific trade that takes a tool (eg. sword) and an item only accessible through a testfor command that detects a certain amount of xp, notifies the player, then gives the second item(eg. emerald). Therefore the villager would trade a Sharpness III sword and 1 paper to give you a Sharpness V sword. This can obviously be adapted for anything you like. A website I recommend is called MCStacker.

Answer (score -1):

Well here's the problem: you are unable to hold multiple objects in your hand!
You are trying to enchant *armor* while holding a *tool* and that's an issue. Try holding the armor instead and enchanting it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using /testfor to find a player with the item then using /replaceitem entity Bob slot.hotbar.0 minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:34,lvl:5}]} 
-That sets the first hotbar slot of the player named "Bob" to a diamond sword.

Answer (score -1):

well the first thing to do is see if you need to verify/enchant.... so check for the level 3 you require for the upgrade.

if less than three skip the rest and reject......
 but if three (or more for lazy way,) you need to figure out everything it holds so>>>>

the following will assume no over enchantments will exist and if it finds an over enchantment this LAZY WAY will set that enchantment to the maximum.  this method is already very long and complimented so this assumption will give you more hair pulling before you decide to kill yourself due to how complicated it is (jk on kill yourself but really, redstone is very simple) so , on to it

there was a list of enchantments listed by what they enchant.... it was down voted by at least three people with their heads so far up their "where the sun don't shine" that you should immediately ignore everything they say.... too bad we don't have a complete list of them.... on to the list.

that list helps to limit what to check for so on the list of the item in question, the range is 32 - 35 but you already know unbreaking so don't have to check for that.

after each check (32, 33, and 35) you will need to save the value returned... rs latch for each level and each enchantment (don't forget an rs latch for level zero of each) then simply set the correct latch for each three

now you have over a dozen rs latches but only three of them are set. a command block tree  can select the correct /give command for giving your upgraded tool. to allow multiple overclocked enchantments would be easier if there is a way to pass a number to the /give command but i doubt that is possible so while this lazy way has only 48 possible /give commands if you were trying to jump increase armor the command tree would be 80,000 - 200,000 depending on what enchantment you were increasing

that all said, I have a less than automatic way to do this but WAY WAY simpler
it is different from you intention so i will place in a separate answer

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is:

```
/give <username> minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {each:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}
```

*This is for a `sharp X` diamond sword.*

This goes all the way up to level 32780.

Comment: How would OP keep the previous enchantments that are already on their weapon, as asked in the question?

Answer (score -3):

You can use 'clear', then 'give' to give an enchanted item.

First, make a command block with 'clear @p diamond_sword', then add a comparator leading into another command block:

'give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:diamond_sword,lvl:5}]}'

You can do the same for armor and other tools.

Comment: This does not keep the enchantments on the item as OP requested.

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize. Is it not an option to give a whole new item with unbreaking and the new enchant?

Answer (score -3):

Easy to do! just go the minecraftcommand.science and there you can make your own commands for example a diamond sword with sharpness 1000000000

(even though that will only do 8 damage as it passes the limit)

Comment: How does this allow OP to enchant an item whilst keeping the item's previous enchantments?

Answer (score -4):

Here is a list of enchantments:

> Armor
>
> - 0.protection
> - 1.fire_protection
> - 2.feather_falling
> - 3.blast_protection
> - 4.projectile_protection
> - 5.resperation
> - 6.aqua infinity
> - 7.thorns
> - 8.depth_strider   Weapons
> - 16.sharpness
> - 17.smite
> - 18.bane of atropods
> - 19.knockback
> - 20.fire aspect
> - 21.looting
>
> Tools
>
> - 32.efficiency
> - 33.silk touch
> - 34.unbreaking
> - 35.fortune
>
> Bows
>
> - 48.power
> - 49.punch
> - 50.flame
> - 51.infinity

Comment: What has this got to do with the question?

Comment: why did I lose reputation for downvoting this?