# /data modify command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command:
`/data modify entity @s Inventory[{Slot:-106b}] set from storage minecraft:datapack Before`
It's supposed to replace the offhand with the NBT in the storage `minecraft:datapack Before`, which has the right NBT. But it just says `Unable to modify player data.` How do I fix this?

Comment: We've got you covered: [How can I modify an item while it is inside the player's inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376895/how-can-i-modify-an-item-while-it-is-inside-the-players-inventory). Be sure to see my answer for 1.17+.