# How to enchant equipped armor using Commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to enchant a player equipped armor using commands?

I've tried this command but it is not working:

```
/execute at @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b}]}] run enchant @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:netherite_helmet}]}] minecraft:vanishing_curse 0
```

I'm trying to enchant a player equipped helmet.

Comment: The `/enchant` command only affects items the player is holding, not armor pieces they are wearing. Hence, this can't be done using that command, and a more complicated solution is needed ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I modify an item while it is inside the player's inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376895/how-can-i-modify-an-item-while-it-is-inside-the-players-inventory)