# How do I copy a player's coordinates into a Lodestone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a manhunt compass using lodestone NBT, avoiding /setworldspawn issues, but I'm having trouble copying the runner’s position array data to the compass' `LodestonePos` NBT tag, considering they are in different formats, and this information will be constantly changing and being updated every tick.

Runner’s Position Format (Doubles): `Pos{0.0d, 0.0d, 0.0d}`

Compass's Lodestone Position Format (Must be integers.): `LodestonePos{X: 0, Y: 0, Z: 0}`

I've tried using item modifiers, `/item modify`, `/execute store result storage`, `/data modify storage`, to no avail. There doesn't seem to be a way to select array positions in paths, and simply setting the value from the player's position won’t work because they are in different formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copying the item into the player's inventory

A great post has already been made regarding this:
[How can I modify an item while it is inside the player's inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376895/how-can-i-modify-an-item-while-it-is-inside-the-players-inventory)

### Setting the lodestone position

These should suffice:

```
execute store result block <shucker box coords> Items[0].tag.LodestonePos.X int 1 run data get entity @p[<however you’re selecting the runner>] Pos[0]

execute store result block <shucker box coords> Items[0].tag.LodestonePos.Y int 1 run data get entity @p[<however you’re selecting the runner>] Pos[1]

execute store result block <shucker box coords> Items[0].tag.LodestonePos.Z int 1 run data get entity @p[<however you’re selecting the runner>] Pos[2]
```

### Now, why does this work?

The player's `Pos` attribute is an array of `double`s (high-precision decimal values), whereas the compass's LodestonePos is an `Object` with attributes `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, which are all `int`s (whole numbers between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1). 
Why the developers decided to have different implementations of coordinates is beyond me, but what this means for *us* is that we have to make three seperate assignments; one for each axis.

#### First, we get the player's position

Let's use `@p` for simplicity

```
data get @p Pos
```

this will return something like `[0d, 3.14d, 12345.678d]`, which is an array of the X, Y, and Z coordinates respectively.

```
data get @p Pos[0]
```

This is just the X coordinate

#### Now let's store a value into an item

Let's use 0 0 0 as the location of a shulker box with a single compass in it

```
execute store result block 0 0 0 Items[0].LodestonePos.X ...
```

This is accessing the X coordinate of the `LodestonePos` attribute of the first item in a shulker box at `0 0 0`, presuming one exists.

#### breaking down the execute command

Now we have

```
execute store result block <shucker box coords> Items[0].tag.LodestonePos.X int 1 run data get entity @p[<however you’re selecting the runner>] Pos[0]
```

which will store the player's x position into the lodestone compass's X attribute.

Let's look at it piece by piece

```
# using the 'store' directive indicates you want to put a value somewhere
execute store 

# you want to store the value you get, not just whether-or-not it succeeds
result 

# you want to put the result into a TileEntity (aka Block Entity) like a chest or shulker box
block

#the location of the tile entity
0 0 0

# the NBT path of the tile entity you want to edit
Items[0].tag.LodestonePos.X

# indicates the resulting value should be converted to type `int`
int

# the scale of the resulting value (just multiplication)
1

# you want to run a command to get a value
run

# the command that should return the desired value
data get entity @p[<however you’re selecting the runner>]
```

#### Making it work for X, Y, and Z

This is relatively simple. Just replace `Pos[0]` with `Pos[1]` for the Y-coodinate, or `Pos[2]` for the Z-coordinate.
Then Replace `LodestonePos.X` with `LodestonePos.Y` and `LodestonePos.Z`, and there you have the 3 different commands

Comment: Could you explain how these commands solve the problem of changing the compass NBT? Why do they work the way they do?

Comment: Nice juicy explanations and markdown for you viewing pleasure ;)

Comment: This worked, thanks, but “Items.[0].LodestonePos.Coord” was missing “.tag.” and should be written as “Items.[0].tag.LodestonePos.Coord” for it to work.

Comment: @HyperBlend fixed. I wasn't able to test it myself so I'm not surprised I missed something :p